# Getting an "Unknown tag"/Liquid error while using Jekyll

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

I did a `bundle update` for my Jekyll site, then tried to run `bundle exec jekyll serve`. I got the following console message:

> Liquid Exception: Liquid syntax error (line 8): Unknown tag 'when' in vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/liquid-4.0.0/lib/liquid/locales/en.yml

I've tried the following:

- uninstall/reinstall Jekyll
- uninstall/reinstall Gems
- uninstall/reinstall Ruby
- install RVM
- do `rm Gemfile.lock`
- run `bundle update`

How can this be resolved?

---

Curiously, when I run `rvm list`, it says  `* ruby-2.4.1 [ x86_64 ]`. Even though the error message says is looking at `2.4.0`. I then ran `rvm list known` to find version 4.0.0 but it wasn't listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you Jekyll directory:

Remove bundle config and gems:

```
rm -r .bundle
rm -r vendor
```

Install gems with bundle:

```
bundle install
```

Run jekyll with it:

```
bundle exec jekyll s
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Comment: Is the jekyll directory universal, or just where the project is?

Comment: If I understand correctly, this is referring to the project directory.

Answer (score 1):

For reference, when I got this error it was because of a badly formed `exclude` command in _config.yml

Comment: Can you elaborate what does 'badly formed' mean? There is nothing bad is my _config.yml and i'm still seeing the issue.

Comment: I got the error when pushing to github and its build process failed. When I removed the `Exclude` section which is needed to exclude the `Git` directory (bizarrely) in the local build, the GitHub build works. I believe that github's version of Jekyll is on 4 and my local builds at 3.92. Wierd, but this post was insightful.